# Get Values from other Dataframe into my Loop for the new Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, if-statement

I have one Dataframe (df1) with TimeCategory as index and different dates as columns and values for each TimeCategory during this day which looks like this:

| TimeCategory | 01.01.2021 |
| --- | --- |
| 0-5 | 3 |
| 5-7 | 0 |
| 7-10 | 1 |
| 10-12 | 5 |
| 12-14 | 5 |

And I have a second dataframe (df2) with the columns Date and TimeCategory.

| Dates | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 01.01.2021 | 0-5 |
| 01.01.2021 | 07-10 |
| 02.01.2021 | 07-10 |
| 02.01.2021 | 05-5 |
| 03.01.2021 | 12-14 |

I added a column to the second dataframe (df2), where I would like to get the values of the first dataframe (df2) based on date and time.

I made two lists out of the different Dates (Date_List) and the different TimeCategory (TimeCategory_List).

My If-Else-Condition works how it is supposed to be.

But I do not know how to get the values (????) from df1 into my loop to write it into my new column [24] of df2.

```
for i in range(0,len(df2)):

    if df2.loc[:,"Date"].iloc[i,] in Date_List and df2.loc[:,"TimeCategory"].iloc[i,] in TimeCategory_List: 
       
       df2.iat[i,24]= ????
    else: 
        df2.iat[i,24]=0
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you don't need a loop but `merge`. You have to reformat your first dataframe with `melt` before merge it with the second one.

```
>>> df1.rename(columns={'TimeCategory': 'Time'}).melt('Time', var_name='Dates') \
       .merge(df2, on=['Time', 'Dates'], how='right')

    Time       Dates  value
0    0-5  01.01.2021    3.0
1  07-10  01.01.2021    NaN  # different from 7-10
2  07-10  02.01.2021    NaN  # different from 7-10
3   05-5  02.01.2021    NaN  # no match from df1
4  12-14  03.01.2021    NaN  # no match from df1
```

**Note**: The problem here is because `'07-10'` is not the same as `'7-10'`, you should use a common syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much the melt function made it possible to merge the two dataframes and that helped me to solve my problem.